# Memory issues converting a huge list of list to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I am having `out of memory` error in the last line of a piece of code which creates a huge list of list in a for loop and then converts it to a data frame.

Here is a minimal reproducible example. I believe there is a lot of additional memory used in the last line. How can I make the code more memory-efficient?

```
import random, pandas, string
def function_to_generate_list():
    def random_string():
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 50))
    return [random_string(), random_string(), random.random()]
len = 10000*20000
df = []
for i in range(len):
    df.append(function_to_generate_list())
df = pandas.DataFrame(df, columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to **pre-allocate** the storage object in the default underlying format used by DataFrame container (i.e. `np.array`). In this way, a DataFrame can be created by directly referencing these arrays instead of making transformed copies of them, thus reducing the memory footprint approximately by half.

## Solution

```
import tracemalloc
import numpy as np

# provided function omitted

tracemalloc.start()

# preallocated output
arr1 = np.zeros(length, dtype=object)
arr2 = np.zeros(length, dtype=object)
arr3 = np.zeros(length, dtype=float)

# assign directly        
for i in range(length):
    arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i] = function_to_generate_list()

# make it a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column1': arr1, 'column2': arr2, 'column3': arr3}
)

print(f"===== Memory Footprint =====")
first, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
print(f"Peak memory usage: {peak} ({peak/1048576:.3f}M)")
```

## Benchmark

`k=5` and `length=1000000` is used in the benchmark. Peak memory usage is reported for different methods. The benchmark is performed on a Core i5-8250U (4C8T) 64-bit laptop running debian 10. The benchmark is performed by inserting the solution code between `tracemalloc.start()` and `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()`.

- This solution: 148.825M  <- winner
- Generator solution: 288.355M
- Original solution: 288.780M

One can see that using a generator won't help, likely because an intermediate non-array object was still generated before producing a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you Bill Huang! In the real case, I know the upper bound on the `length` but do not know exactly how much of it would be filled. In other words, there is an if condition before calling `function_to_generate_list()`. In this case, I think I can still get arrays of size `length`, and `drop` the unfilled rows after making the data frame? Or would there be a better way?

Comment: I don't think there would be a robust workaround because there is always a chance that the theoretical upper bound would be hit. The only thing you can do is finding more space available for your objects. For instance, use [h5py](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable) to store the output arrays on a hard disk.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have enough space for the case the upper bound is hit, but I have to remove the unfilled rows because these should not be included in the final data frame. So my last question is more about whether the `drop` operation is efficient. If I do an in-place `drop` operation by calling `df.drop(df.index[df.column1==0], inplace=True)` to remove unfilled rows, this does not add a lot of memory usage right? I mean, data frame is not copied anywhere during `drop`?

Comment: I think this is already another question, as the implementation may have to be adjusted according to this additional information. You may post a separate follow-up question.

Comment: It may seem quite trivial for a lot of people, but for those who wonder where `1048576` comes from: To get the memory size in MB, we need to convert the bytes to megabytes. This is done by dividing by 1024*1024 or 1,048,576.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

When you do this `df.append(function_to_generate_list())` you don't actually need to have all values stored at once. When you create a dataframe, it will only iterate over each value once, so you only need one value at a time. And that is what generators do.

You could modify your last line like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame((function_to_generate_list() for _ in range(length)), 
                      columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
```

Also note that i renamed `len` to `length`. Because when you create a variable `len` you overwrite a built-in function `len`.

Comment: Thanks @go2nirvana! I am not familiar to generators. Just changing the the last four lines to what you wrote above is enough, or should I make changes (such as replacing `return` with `yield`) in `function_to_generate_list` definition as well?

Comment: This answer does not reduce memory footprint because an intermediate non-array object is still to be created. See my answer for the proof.